# C++ script builder and evaluator in Flutter

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to build a tool in flutter that runs C++ code and outputs the results. The thing is that I want to let the user input some simple C++ code (1 file, with a main function), and run it on our platform, we should just give some example inputs to the C++ script that the user sent and see what are the outputs. I think that codecademy has a feature like this. Does anybody know how I could compile C++ code from flutter and run it on different inputs? Also, how do I take text that it's inputed by the user in a textfield and transform it into a runable C++ script.

Answer (score 0):

I Personally do not know a whole lot about dart or flutter, but from a glimpse at the documentation, I couldn't find anything relating to executing processes on the host computer. I'm not entirely sure if its possible using your desired stack. With this said, I can give you a super simple flow-down of what you need to do to achieve your goal. There are more comprehensive ways to do this with added security mechanisms in place, but will not be discussed here.

Word of caution - If you are intending to put this up on the open web, be ready for someone to execute some malicious code on your web-server and hack you.

=====

Requisite: The machine running web-sever needs to be running Linux and have GCC installed. I assume your using Linux?? If not, Use windows + MSVC, but may be harder to do.

1. Create website-interface with textfield for the C++ code, a textfield for the standard out / error, and a big compile button.
2. On click of the button, send the c++ code in the textfield to dart, or what ever server you have / must use to get this working.
3. The web-server will simply save this code on the web-servers filesystem in a uniquely named file.
4. The web-server will then need to start a "GCC compiler process" to compile the saved file in step 3, and wait until it generates an executable (or error). Capture the GCC compiler output in case it fails.
5. If the file successfully compiled, then the web-server must then run the executable and capture the standard output / error. *SECURITY CAUTION* executing unknown code could be dangerous.
6. The web-server will respond with the output back to the client
7. The client will place the output in the output-textfield